# Ember inside static page as a part of the page - how can I use named anchors?

Tags: ember.js

Ember is only a part of the app and let's suppose I have the following structure:

```
<header>title</header>
<a href="#faq">go to faq</a>
<div id="ember-container"></div>
<div id="faq">...</div>
```

The problems is that Ember tries to intercept the named anchor as a route. How can I make it so that both go with one another?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for the `rootElement` property:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#ember-container'
});
```

Search `rootElement` in the api doc for [Ember.Application](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html).

Comment: The Ember part is created with the help of rootElement. The problem is that whenever I click on a named anchor like `#faq` that is outside the Ember container, Ember's Router thinks that I going to go to the `faq` route, but I'd like to use a plain anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It turned out that the url set in the admin panel was absolute - setting it to `#faq` solved the problem. Sorry that the question didn't reflect this.